# How do I exclude a cutpath area in VCarve?

Tags: milling, cnc

I'm using a VCarve and a ShopBot CNC to attempt an excluded area from being milled. Regarding the image below, I can only figure out how to remove the outer area in red, as the green area is in the cutpath of the red area.

How can I create pocket cutpath with excludes an area within it?

[image: 3D model of excluded area]

**Indirectly related**
If someone has enough points to add keywords, `CNC`, and `VCarve` would be useful terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out after watching a Youtube video. In short, two vector paths need to be selected for the pocket cut path (a starting and ending vector).

[image: 2D view]

[image: 3D view]